# Create a menu on avatar click

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've been searching for quite a while now, and I don't know if I'm not searching the correct term, but I want to make a menu that displays over the current screen when you click on your avatar.

Like this one from Google:

[image: Avatar menu]

Or this one from Facebook:

[image: Facebook notify drawer]

I tried using `showMenu()`, but this one requires that I use `PopUpMenuItem()` which is, but it does not allow customizing the whole menu. For what I understand, I have to draw a `Material()` widget or `Stack()` over the current screen, but I have no knowledge on that.

Comment: For 1st one, you can use `Column` on `AlertDialog(content:Column(..))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an [OverlayEntry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry-class.html). They're tricky, and there are packages that help you manage overlays more easily. Please check these:

https://pub.dev/packages/modals

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal

Comment: flutter_portal really helped me, many thanks!